# ¿por que no me muestra el id del proveedor especifico que le pongo?

Tags: mysql, sql

uso este codigo y me falla en el where al final, sin el todo va bien pero necesito saber ese id especifico.

```sql
SELECT t_proveedores.nombre, t_proveedores.apellido, t_proveedores.id_proveedor, t_productos.marca, t_productos.modelo
FROM t_proveedores
INNER JOIN t_productos
ON t_proveedores.id_proveedor = t_productos.id_proveedor
WHERE id_proveedor = 45636
```

Comment: Y esa consulta da algún error?

Comment: Ponle el nombre de la tabla que quieres apuntar el `where` `id_proveedor`.

Comment: la consulta da error de sintax en la linea 3 , ya intente poniendo la tabla

Comment: Siempre la pregunta debe venir acompañada del mensaje de error por favor, ese error que mencionas colocalo completo

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que especificar a que tabla pertenece ese **idproveedor** ya que ambas tablas tienen un campo llamado **idproveedor**.

Podría ser:

```sql
where proveedores.idProveedor = idBuscado
```

O

```sql
where producto.idProveedor = idBuscado
```

Comment: uff si hermano me faltaba agregar la tabla, gracias